# Centering inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to center a div in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div)

I have a big DIV that has a width and height of of 100% so it takes up the whole browser. I also have a another DIV inside that with a width of 1024px and a height of 400px. I was wondering what the best method of centering the div both horizontally and vertically would be? I also want it to stay in the center when the browser is resized. Is there a jQuery plugin, some handy javascript or can I do this simply using CSS.

The Markup

```
.bigdiv{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-color:#eee;
}
.smalldiv{
height:400px;
width:1024px;
background-color:#ccc;
}

<div class="bigdiv">
<div class="smalldiv"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help and advice!

Comment: This question has been answered many times. Try searching in Stack Overflow. The key is `position: absolute`, `margin-left: -width/2`,  `margin-top: -height/2`, and container with `position: relative`.

Comment: @elclanrs and add 'top:50%;left:50%;' to the small div

Comment: @gion_13: Right! Forgot about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this is how to get it to center.

```
.bigdiv{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-color:#eee;
position:relative;
}
.smalldiv{
height:400px;
width:1024px;
background-color:#ccc;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin-left:512px;
margin-top:200px;
}

<div class="bigdiv">
<div class="smalldiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using, `margin:0 auto;`

```
.smalldiv{
height:400px;
width:1024px;
background-color:#ccc;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily give the `margin:auto;` to you child div for your desired results

**HTML**

```
<div class="bigdiv">
<div class="smalldiv"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .bigdiv{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#eee;
    }
    .smalldiv{
    height:400px;
    width:1024px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    margin:auto;
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D2EBA/)

Comment: you also have to add html{height:100%;}body{height:100%;}​ to the css. but it does not work because margin auto does not work on the vertical. Use the one i posted below.

Answer (score -1):

use `text-align:center` in your larger div
and `margin:0 auto`
 in your inner div